# Java enums: implementing common methods, avoiding duplication

Tags: java, enums, abstraction, java-6, code-duplication

Let's say that I have two differents enumeration

```
public enum SomeEnumClass {

    private static  final SomeEnumClass[]   mValues = SomeEnumClass .values();
    ONE(1), TWO(2), THREE(3);

}

public enum OtherEnumClass {
    private static  final OtherEnumClass[]  mValues = OtherEnumClass .values();
    Monday(1), Tuesday(2), Wednesday(3), Thrusday(4), Friday(5), Saturday(6), Sunday(7)

}
```

The enum have in common the type of data they carry (here, an int), and differ in their name and number of possible values.

For each of those enum, I have several method to implements, which are strictly identical. Example:

```
        public static OtherEnumClass getCell(int index)
    {
        if (index < OtherEnumClass .mValues.length )
        {
            return OtherEnumClass .mValues[index];              
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid " + OtherEnumClass .class.getSimpleName() + " value: " + index);
    }
```

I am trying to find a way to avoid duplication of those methods, like I would do with abstract classes. But so far I am coming with nothing.

We are using java 1.6 and cannot upgrade for now. Any help is appreciated. thanks.

Comment: An enum can't extend a class nor another enum, so either you write the method once for each (and ideally make the enum implement an interface that defines the method), or you write the code outside of the enums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code example is a bit misleading as it returns the constant with the same ordinal rather than the one with the same property value. In order to abstract the search for a constant with a property value, you have to abstract the property, e.g.

```
interface TypeWithIntProperty {
  int getProperty();
}
enum Number implements TypeWithIntProperty {
  ONE(1), TWO(2), THREE(3);

  private final int value;

  Number(int value) {
    this.value=value;
  }
  public int getProperty() {
    return value;
  }
}
enum DayOfWeek implements TypeWithIntProperty {
  Monday(1), Tuesday(2), Wednesday(3), Thrusday(4), Friday(5), Saturday(6), Sunday(7);

  private final int value;

  DayOfWeek(int value) {
    this.value=value;
  }
  public int getProperty() {
    return value;
  }
}

public class Helper {
  public static <E extends Enum<E>&TypeWithIntProperty>
                E getEnumItem(Class<E> type, int value) {
    for(E constant: type.getEnumConstants())
      if(value == constant.getProperty())
        return constant;
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("no constant with "+value+" in "+type);
  }
}
```

```
DayOfWeek day=Helper.getEnumItem(DayOfWeek.class, 7);
Number no=Helper.getEnumItem(Number.class, 2);
```

If the properties have different types, you can make the interface generic:

```
interface TypeWithIntProperty<T> {
  T getProperty();
}
enum Number implements TypeWithIntProperty<String> {
  ONE, TWO, THREE;

  public String getProperty() {
    return name().toLowerCase();
  }
}
enum DayOfWeek implements TypeWithIntProperty<Integer> {
  Monday(1), Tuesday(2), Wednesday(3), Thrusday(4), Friday(5), Saturday(6), Sunday(7);

  private final int value;

  DayOfWeek(int value) {
    this.value=value;
  }
  public Integer getProperty() {
    return value;
  }
}

public class Helper {
  public static <E extends Enum<E>&TypeWithIntProperty<P>,P>
                  E getEnumItem(Class<E> type, P value) {
    for(E constant: type.getEnumConstants())
      if(value.equals(constant.getProperty()))
        return constant;
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("no constant with "+value+" in "+type);
  }
}
```

```
DayOfWeek day=Helper.getEnumItem(DayOfWeek.class, 7);
Number no=Helper.getEnumItem(Number.class, "two");
```

A cleaner, but more verbose (under Java 6) alternative is to separate the property abstraction from the type having the property:

```
interface Property<T,V> {
  V get(T owner);
}
enum Number {
  ONE, TWO, THREE;
  static final Property<Number,String> NAME=new Property<Number,String>() {
    public String get(Number owner) { return owner.getName(); }
  };

  public String getName() {
    return name().toLowerCase();
  }
}
enum DayOfWeek {
  Monday(1), Tuesday(2), Wednesday(3), Thrusday(4), Friday(5), Saturday(6), Sunday(7);
  static final Property<DayOfWeek,Integer> INDEX=new Property<DayOfWeek,Integer>() {
    public Integer get(DayOfWeek owner) { return owner.getIndex(); }
  };

  private final int index;

  DayOfWeek(int value) {
    this.index=value;
  }
  public int getIndex() {
    return index;
  }
}
public class Helper {
  public static <E extends Enum<E>,P>
                  E getEnumItem(Class<E> type, Property<E,P> prop, P value) {
    for(E constant: type.getEnumConstants())
      if(value.equals(prop.get(constant)))
        return constant;
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("no constant with "+value+" in "+type);
  }
}
```

```
DayOfWeek day=Helper.getEnumItem(DayOfWeek.class, DayOfWeek.INDEX, 7);
Number no=Helper.getEnumItem(Number.class, Number.NAME, "two");
```

This would be much simpler in Java 8 where you can implement `Property` as `DayOfWeek::getIndex` or `Number::getName` instead of inner classes, on the other hand, since we don’t benefit from the single-method interface in Java 6, we can turn this into an advantage by using an abstract base class which can provide the functionality, now even with caching:

```
abstract class Property<T extends Enum<T>,V> {
  final Class<T> type;
  final Map<V,T> map;
  Property(Class<T> type) {
    this.type=type;
    map=new HashMap<V, T>();
    for(T constant: type.getEnumConstants())
    {
      T old = map.put(get(constant), constant);
      if(old!=null)
        throw new IllegalStateException("values not unique: "+get(constant));
    }
  }
  abstract V get(T owner);
  T getConstant(V value) {
    T constant=map.get(value);
    if(constant==null)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("no constant "+value+" in "+type);
    return constant;
  }
}
enum Number {
  ONE, TWO, THREE;
  static final Property<Number,String> NAME=new Property<Number,String>(Number.class) {
    public String get(Number owner) { return owner.getName(); }
  };

  public String getName() {
    return name().toLowerCase();
  }
}
enum DayOfWeek {
  Monday(1), Tuesday(2), Wednesday(3), Thrusday(4), Friday(5), Saturday(6), Sunday(7);
  static final Property<DayOfWeek,Integer> INDEX
               =new Property<DayOfWeek,Integer>(DayOfWeek.class) {
    public Integer get(DayOfWeek owner) { return owner.getIndex(); }
  };

  private final int index;

  DayOfWeek(int value) {
    this.index=value;
  }
  public int getIndex() {
    return index;
  }
}
```

```
DayOfWeek day=DayOfWeek.INDEX.getConstant(7);
Number no=Number.NAME.getConstant("two");
```

Comment: I am using an helper class and it's work very well. I can centralize code for several enumerations here. The code overall is still messy in my opinion, but I guess it's the best I can do here.

Question, what means the & in <E extends Enum<E>&TypeWithIntProperty> ?
Why is it not a comma ?

Comment: It’s called an *intersection type*. The type of `E` must be an `enum` (extend `Enum<E>`) *and* it must implement `TypeWithIntProperty` at the same type. A comma is for declaring multiple type parameters, but this is a single type parameter with multiple constraints.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this precision !

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
public enum SomeEnumClass {

    ONE, TWO, THREE;

}

public enum OtherEnumClass {

    Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thrusday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday

}

public static <E extends Enum> E getEnumItem(Class<E> type, int index){
    E[] values = type.getEnumConstants();
    if (index >= 0 && index < values.length){
        return values[index];
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("...");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getEnum(SomeEnumClass.class, 0));
    System.out.println(getEnum(OtherEnumClass.class, 3));
    System.out.println(getEnum(SomeEnumClass.class, 2));
    System.out.println(getEnum(OtherEnumClass.class, 6));
}
```

It prints:

```
ONE
Thrusday
THREE
Sunday
```

EDITED:
This is a similar idea to @dasblinkenlight

```
public enum SomeEnumClass {

    ONE, TWO, THREE;

    public static SomeEnumClass getCell(int index) {
        return Utility.getEnumItem(SomeEnumClass.class, index);
    }
}

public enum OtherEnumClass {

    Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thrusday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday;

    public static OtherEnumClass getCell(int index) {
        return Utility.getEnumItem(OtherEnumClass.class, index);
    }
}

public static class Utility {

    public static <E extends Enum> E getEnumItem(Class<E> type, int index) {
        E[] values = type.getEnumConstants();
        if (index >= 0 && index < values.length) {
            return values[index];
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("...");
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Utility.getEnumItem(SomeEnumClass.class, 0));
    System.out.println(Utility.getEnumItem(OtherEnumClass.class, 3));
    System.out.println(Utility.getEnumItem(SomeEnumClass.class, 2));
    System.out.println(Utility.getEnumItem(OtherEnumClass.class, 6));
}
```

Comment: This would be working in this case, however I will have some methods that are dependant of what the enum actually are. So while your "getEnumItem" is going to work for any enum, another method which would return an int or a string based on the member that the enum contain won't.
This could be a solution but it won't be as safe as I wish

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your implementations into a generic helper class, and use it in all your implementations. Unfortunately, you would have to copy the calls into the helper; Default methods of Java 8 address this problem, but you cannot leverage them since you are limited to Java 6.

```
// Helper owns the static members that you used to add to your enums directly
class CellHelper<T> {
    final T[] mValues;
    final Class<T> cls;
    // Helper needs Class<T> to work around type erasure
    public CellHelper(T[] values, Class<T> c) {
        mValues = values;
        cls = c;
    }
    public T getCell(int index) {
        if (index < mValues.length ) {
            return mValues[index];              
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid " + cls.getSimpleName() + " value: " + index);
    }
}

enum SomeEnumClass {
    ONE(1), TWO(2), THREE(3);
    SomeEnumClass(int n){}
    // This variable hosts your static data, along with shared behavior
    private static  final CellHelper<SomeEnumClass> helper = new CellHelper(SomeEnumClass.values(), SomeEnumClass.class);
    // Delegate the calls for shared functionality to the helper object
    public static SomeEnumClass getCell(int i) {return helper.getCell(i);}
}

enum OtherEnumClass {
    Monday(1), Tuesday(2), Wednesday(3), Thrusday(4), Friday(5), Saturday(6), Sunday(7);
    OtherEnumClass(int n){}
    private static  final CellHelper<OtherEnumClass> helper = new CellHelper(OtherEnumClass.values(), OtherEnumClass.class);
    public static OtherEnumClass getCell(int i) {return helper.getCell(i);}
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/txAdvK)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an interface:

```
public interface Indexed<E extends Enum> {

    default public E getByIndex(int index) {
        if (!this.getClass().isEnum()) {
            //not implemented on enum, you can do as you like here
        }
        Enum<?>[] vals = (Enum<?>[]) this.getClass().getEnumConstants();
        if (index < 0 || index >= vals.length) {
            //illegal arg exception
        }
        return (E) vals[index];
    }

}
```

Then in implementation:

```
public enum MyEnum implements Indexed<MyEnum> {
    ONE,
    TWO,
    THREE,
    ;
}
```

Also to note, instead of supplying those indexes manually, you can just use `Enum#ordinal`.

This is a Java 8 only solution, since there are no defaulted methods in previous Java versions. Additionally this has a bit of an awkward/disadvantageous usage, since it would be an instance method (though you could make it static if you desire).

For earlier versions, you need a way to provide the class type since there isn't really a different way of providing it for an enum, in which you'd use David's answer above.

Comment: OP Said: _We are using java 1.6 and cannot upgrade for now._

Comment: Well, rip. There's a flaw in this as well since it's non-static. Going to improve it, just wanted to get the idea down for now as an option.

Comment: Thanks for this, however I also have to add that I cannot get rid of the enum member, which in my example is an int, but In my code is actually a state enum, or a string.

Answer (score 0):

The Helper class is really heplful. We already started having issue with bad factories, causing enums to be order dependant - which is a total aberation -

Now I refactored all enums classes so they use the helper and a single factory. However I changed it's signature the following way:

```
public static <E extends Enum<E> & IEnumWithValue> E factory(final E[] iConstants, int iValue) throws IllegalArgumentException
```

In my enum class I have a member defined as this:

```
private static  final MyEnum[]  mValues = MyEnum.values();
```

This way, I do not have to pass the enum type in argument, and I do not have to multiply calls to *values()* or *class.getEnumConstants()*